# Android RxJava Thread Reusal, Is it a bad practice?

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java2, android-mvvm

I am using retrofit and Rxjava to handle api calls for my mvvm android application. Based on some tutorial, i am currently using RxJava like this.

ViewModel.java

```
CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

private void fetchTodolist(){
        loading.setValue(true);
        disposable.add(
                service.getToDoList("A1833")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<ApiResponse<ArrayList<TodoItem>>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ApiResponse<ArrayList<TodoItem>> value) {
                        if(value.getStatus() == 200){
                            //on call success code
                        } else {
                            //on call rejected code
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        // on call error code
                    }
                })
        );
    }
```

And now i want to cache the result of the api call on successful call into room database. So i need to use another async method and tried to reuse the new thread i created before. And here's the code.

```
private void fetchTodolist(){
        loading.setValue(true);
        Scheduler a = Schedulers.newThread();
        disposable.add(
                service.getToDoList("A1833")
                .subscribeOn(a)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<ApiResponse<ArrayList<TodoItem>>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ApiResponse<ArrayList<TodoItem>> value) {
                        if(value.getStatus() == 200){

                            a.scheduleDirect(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                long inserted = dao.insert(value);
                            }

                        });
                        } else {
                            //on call rejected code
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        // on call error code
                    }
                })
        );
    }
```

I wonder if it is a bad practice and will lead to a serious problem. And if so, what's the alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Schedulers` uses cached references thus `newThread()` returns the same `Scheduler` instance.

```
Schedulers.newThread() == Schedulers.newThread()
```

Generally you should avoid using `newThread` because it creates a new thread for every application of the operator. So if you run the sequence multiple times, new worker threads are created and dismissed without any kind of reuse. This is especially true for `newThread().scheduleDirect` which will start a new thread just for that single runnable and stop it afterwards.

It is recommended you use `Schedulers.io()` for IO operations so that those underlying worker threads are reused as much as possible later.